# How to search a 2D char array and see if any sequence of characters in each row is a word in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, character

I have a method that is supposed to look at rows of a 2D char array and see if any sequence of letters is a word. For example if row 0 of the char array is:        `{'b','o','x','e','n'}`
The method should print out "box oxen." 
However, when I try to go through the entire array, the method only shows the found characters in the last row the array.
Is there a way I can fix my code so that it reads through all rows of the array, rather than just the last row?

```
public static void locateWords(char [][] ch, String [] dictionary, int rowLength, int colLength, ArrayList<String> foundWords){
        StringBuilder rowChars = new StringBuilder(); //contains each row of characters in 2d array
            for(int i = 0; i<rowLength; i++){
                for (int start = 0; start < rowLength; start++){
                    for(int j = 1; j < colLength; j++){
                        rowChars.append(ch[start][j]);
                        if (checkWord(dictionary, rowChars.toString())) {
                           //checkWord() method checks to see if the characters form a word
                            foundWords.add(rowChars.toString());
                    }                  
                }
            }
            rowChars.delete(0, colLength); // clears out rowChars for next row
        }
    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that a `char` cannot store special characters (for example, anything from the Mandarin alphabet). If you are using simple ascii, that's fine, but it's something to watch out for.

Comment: In Java a `char` is a Unicode character. So it can store special characters.

Comment: It looks like you are confusing rows and columns here. You are using `rowLength` and `colLength` the wrong way around. And why do you need `rowLength` and `colLength` as arguments? You can just look at the size of the array instead. Also `start` seems to be the start of the potential word to test so `ch[start][j]` is not correct since start is not the column index. Furthermore you are deleteting `rowChars` at the wrong place. It needs to be cleared after each row.

Comment: Isn't this line `rowChars.delete(0, colLength); // clears out rowChars for next row` clearing out the previous row?  That could be your problem.